# What a particular Flex framework can bring more advantages for this case?

Tags: apache-flex, design-patterns, frameworks

I had experiences using Mate and Parsley. But for now, I'm using none.

For instance, I'm using observer and singleton patterns like following.

`RegisterView.mxml` implements `IRegisterAction` interface

```
    function onBtnRegisterClick(){
        var action:RegisterAction = new RegisterAction();
        action.addActionListener(this);
        action.execute(ServicesSingleton.getCustomerService(),customer);
    }
    ......
    function registerCallback(customer:Customer ):void{
        .......
    }
```

This is my interface `IRegisterAction.as`

```
function registerCallback(customer:Customer ):void;
```

My question is "What additional benefits I will get, if I use a particular framework ?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you implemented your own observer pattern based on how java works.
Why didn't use the standard flash observer mechanism based on events?

A side of that, your view is coupled to the service, not a good practice at all. 
Also, you implemented your service as a Singleton. That will make impossible changing the implementation of your service if you decide to do some unit/integration testing.

All the "second generation" frameworks (Mate, Parsley, Swiz, Robotlegs, Tide...) will help you create a  architecture based on dependency injection and messaging in a fully decoupled manner.

Comment: One more question. How can I design to synchronize the returned results from the dispatched events ? For example, after the user registration was done successfully, the alert dialog box will show "Successfully Register".

Comment: We use the CommandResult metatag with Parsley but each framework provides its own solution to do that.

Comment: To add to what Florian said, by using a known Framework you reduce the amount of time developing and debugging specific features since they're already in use by a lot of people.  Second, you standardize your process and training since you can hire someone that already has expertise in that framework already instead of him learning a new and probably not so good internal framework.  And third, frameworks like Parsley are optimized for the Flex/Flash world.

Comment: Thanks Florian and J_A_X. Thanks for your helps.